# Dynamically created highchart not showing bars/lines

Tags: highcharts

I'm showing some data in a program I made using the Highcharts library. Two pretty much identical pieces of code gave very different results (the first, having 2 lines, not showing anything and the second, having 1 line, showing what I expect). To make sure I didn't do anything wrong in the configuration of the chart I copied the following code [from the highcharts website](http://docs.highcharts.com/#your-first-chart) and left it exactly as-is but it yields an unexpected result:

```
var chartinfo = {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]
}

$("#" + graphid).highcharts(chartinfo);
```

This generates the following chart:

[image: Generated graph]

As you can see (click image to enlarge) it has the expected scale (0 - 7.5 where the range is 0-7). I put a breakpoint (using Chrome) on line 14503 of highcharts.src.js (v3.0.1) which is the start of the `drawTracker` function.

The `drawTracker` gets called for the graph that is displayed correctly (obviously), but doesn't get called for the above graph. So something goes wrong between the point where the scale is determined or executed and the actual drawing.

Any insight into the problem would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

It appears this only happens to the first graph on the page. When I switch them around (the method calls) the first one doesn't show the line and the second one does show the bars (the above code). So what I'd like to find out is why the fist graph isn't showing it's content and the second one does show its content.

Comment: I found the solution. Will answer as soon as I can so people that find themselves with this problem can be helped.

Comment: Probably it looks like a problem with $("#" + graphid).highcharts(chartinfo); this line and graphid variable.

Comment: No the problem wasn't with that. I checked everything multiple times and it's correct. The graph shows but the lines/bars don't show. I have already posted the solution to this particular problem down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The containers in which the charts are drawn are added dynamically by the next line of code (about the same for all variations of graphs in my case):

```
$('#' + container).html($('#' + container).html() + "<div class=\"graph\" id=\"" + graphid + "\"></div>");
```

This used to work when I used the Elycharts library but using Highcharts this gave the problem that the graph was replaced by a copy before the lines were properly drawn. I fixed this by doing the following:

```
$('#' + container).append("<div class=\"graph\" id=\"" + graphid + "\"></div>");
```

jQuery's append method adds the new html to the existing without touching the existing html. This allows the script to finish the drawing of the lines/bars/whatever you want to draw.

Comment: Generally append() is better solution.

Comment: As I notieced in this case! :)